# How to optimize inserting bulk data into Supabase?

Tags: next.js, prisma, supabase

I’m new to Supabase and created an application to simulate a game scoring app. I have the following tables: weeks, rounds, games, subgames, scores.

In this instance, I’m generating a set of data with 10 weeks, 10 rounds per week, 10 games per round, 20 subgames per game and 120 scores per subgame. All linked by its relevant id column (auto increment); weekId, roundId, gameId, subgameId.

Here’s the problem: generating all these takes an hour to complete and half the time, it doesn’t completely create them. It randomly stops at different point; sometimes stopping at Round 3, at times up till Round 8 or even Round 10 but halfway through the games, etc.

Here’s what I would like to achieve:

1. 100% of the time to completely creat all records (not randomly)
2. Completely create all records in less than 1 minute.

Appreciate any feedback to point me the right direction.

Thanks

Here’s my current implementation in pseudocode:

```
For each weeks
  Await prisma.week.create(…)
  For each rounds
    Await prisma.round.create(weekId,…)
    For each games
      Await prisma.game.create(roundId,…)
      For each subgames
        Await prisma.subgame.create(gameId,…)
        For each scores 
          Await prisma.score.create(subgameId,…)
```